# How can I dynamically populate an address in another textbox when user enter zip code?

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to dynamically populate an address from a getAdd($Url) function to textbox(addressD) when user keying postal code in another textbox(postalCode). but no value is populated to the addressD textbox at all. can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
<?php
  function getAdd($Url){

      if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
          die('cURL is not installed. Install and try again.');
      }

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gothere.sg/a/search?q='.$Url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);


        $trimData = strstr($output, 'locf');
        $extractData = substr($trimData, 13);
        $findPos = strpos($extractData, '<');
        $extractData2 = substr($extractData, 0, $findPos);

        echo "<script type="text/javascript">";
        echo "document.getElementByID('addressD').value = $extractData2";
        echo "</script>";
  }
?>

<html>
<body>
    <form id="contact-form" method="post">
       Postal Code*:
       <input type="text" name="postalCode" value="" onkeypress="getAdd(this.value)" />    

       Address*:
       <input type="text" name="addressD" id="addressD" value="" />    
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are on a wrong way my friend. The function you have written in php and you are using it in javascript. First of all you have to learn about the working of php (Server side language) and javascript (Clint side language) . Use ajax for it

Answer (score 0):

When you press the button, the browser tries to execute a javascript function called `getAdd()`. However, you've created a php function called `getAdd()` - that won't work. You cannot call a server-side function from the browser without using ajax calls. The php function is never sent to the user's browser, it's parsed by the server and then the html beneath it is sent out.

Comment: Honestly, your best bet is to google around for when to use javascript and when to use php. Then, when you understand why this doesn't work, you can google for making jquery ajax calls.